# Executing JavaScript code on Windows Store App

Tags: javascript, windows-phone-8, windows-store-apps, win-universal-app, windows-10

I have a JavaScript library (*library.js file*) with functions that I need to invoke from projects targeting multiple platforms (Mac, Windows Desktop, Windows 8.1, Android, etc..). For example, lets say I have an algorithm that that takes input A and returns B. The JavaScript library that has the implementation for translating A --> B should be reused across all platforms

For Windows **RT, 8.1, 10** XAML based C# Store Apps, what options do I have to execute a JavaScript script at runtime? I am looking for a JavaScript engine that could execute scripts by taking input parameters and return me a value.

So far, I have found out that [JINT](https://github.com/sebastienros/jint) interpreter works on 8.1, but the performance is slow for large scripts and I am looking for a tested and trusted JavaScript compiler similar to JavaScriptCore that iOS/Mac uses.

Answer (score 2):

For Windows 8.x, you can host a hidden WebView control and load the JavaScript into that.

For Windows 10 Universal Apps, you can [directly host the JavaScript runtime](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn249673(v=vs.94).aspx). It is exposed as a Win32 C-style API (not WinRT) so you will need to use some native code to get it working.

Comment: This is what I'd recommend, using the WebView's InvokeScriptAsync method to call code inside the Webview. You can also use window.external.notify to raise events from the Webview. With these, you can have two-way communication between the app and code in the Webview.

Comment: Does this take input parameters and give other parameter as output?

Answer (score 0):

> For Windows RT, 8.1, 10 XAML based C# Store Apps, what options do I
>   have to execute a JavaScript script at runtime?

Essentially, you need a high performance JavaScript Engine like Google V8 on WinRT, but as far as I know, no such open source engine so far.
My suggestion is hosting the JavaScript code on server side and consume it as a service or converting the JavaScript algorithm to C# code.

Comment: The built-in Windows JavaScript engine is high-performance and available to UWP.